# Node.js process, running in Docker container hangs without exiting or throwing when out of memory

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I've stumbled upon an interesting problem recently: I have an Express Node.js application and I was working on deploying it to AWS ECS using Docker image. However, it deployed correctly, the health checks were failing and after examining the logs I've found that process just hangs indefinitely during Express initialization without giving any errors.

At first I was thinking that it was caused by some network miss-configuration, which prevented the process from starting a listener on HTTP port, but after very tedious examination, I've noticed, that default memory limit was in place and it was only 50 MB of RAM, when process actually required a little bit more. After increasing the memory limit it started to work fine.

- **Why was it hanging without giving any errors at all. Isn't the Node process should exit with error when this happens?**
- **How do I prevent such problems in the future? I.e. I want my process to be terminated with meaningful error, when such situation occurs.**

Thank you!

Comment: Could we get some code?

Comment: It's pretty complicated Enterprise application, written in TypeScript with Dependency Injection, services and such. I'm not quite sure how to publish it here, or what peaces of the code could be related to the problem. I was hoping for a more generic answer or a suggestion, which will steer me in the right direction. Probably someone had the similar experience in the past.